# AWS temporary files before uploading to S3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Laravel app allows users to upload images. Currently, when the user uploads their images, they are stored in a temporary location on the server. A cron job then modifies the uploaded images (compresses them, etc.), and uploads them to S3. Any temporary files older than 48 hours that failed to upload to S3 are deleted by another cron job.

I've set up an Elastic Beanstalk environment, but it's occurred to me that storing uploaded images in a temporary directory on an instance is risky because instances can be created and destroyed when necessary.

How and where, then, would I store these temporary files so that they're not at risk of being deleted by an instance?

Comment: I happen to be working on the exact same issue right now. Can't we use the AWS SDK to point the initial upload to an S3 bucket, instead of our server? Then the cron jobs do their work on this "temp" S3 bucket, and in the end upload to the permanent S3 bucket.

Comment: That would work, but I'm looking for a way to avoid uploading temporary files to S3, if that's possible (to avoid the costs associated).

Comment: Ah, well with Elastic Beanstalk I think we're always at risk of an ec2 instance being destroyed, and that's not something we can curtail as far as I know unless you want to get rid of all of the scaling and failure recovery benefits. The file has to go somewhere, other options would be a standalone ec2 instance that is controlled directly by you (so you know it won't be shut down), a file hosting service e.g. imgur maybe?, but those have costs associated as well of course.

Comment: All the research I've done points to having to use S3, so unless someone says otherwise, I'll most likely have to go with that. Definitely don't want to use another file hosting service...feels dirty.

Comment: S3 definitely seems like the best option.

Comment: Consider uploading the originals directly to S3 so that you don't have to proxy the upload via your server. Also consider using event-based Lambda functions to convert the images from their original source format & location to your desired format & location.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, I think that uploading the file to S3 is the best option. As far as I know, it's not possible to stop Elastic Beanstalk from destroying an ec2 instance, unless you want to get rid of all of the scaling and instance failure/autoreplacement features.

One option I don't know much about may be AWS EBS. "Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) provides persistent block storage volumes for use with Amazon EC2 instances in the AWS Cloud." I don't have any direct experience with EBS, the overriding question of course would be if EBS is truly persistent, even after an ec2 instance is destroyed. As EBS has costs associated with it, it seems like since you are already using S3, S3 would be the way to go.

Comment: If anyone can explain the differences between S3 and EBS, and which is most appropriate in my situation, please do.

Comment: @user1465627 Object storage vs block storage. See https://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/amazon-s3-vs-amazon-ebs/. In your case, you should probably be using S3.

Answer (score 2):

S3 has a feature called [object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) you can use to have files deleted automatically by setting them them to expire 2 days after they're uploaded.

You can either:

A) Prefix the temporary files to put them in an S3 psuedo-folder (i.e., `Temp/`), apply the object lifecycle expire rule to that specific prefix (or "folder"), and use the files in there as a source of truth for the new files derived from it post-manipulation.

or

B) Create an S3 bucket specifically for temporary files. Manipulate the files from there and copy to the production bucket.